# Silverstripe 3.0:Add Sub-tabs under settings->main tab keeping the default fields in a separate tab

Tags: silverstripe

I have added new Sub Tabs Under The Settings->Main Tab in The Silverstripe 3.0 Back-End using the following code:

public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

```
   $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TabSet('Tab1'),'Theme');
   $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main.Tab1', new Tab('SubTab1',new HTMLEditorField("Text", "Text")));
   $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main.Tab1', new Tab('SubTab2', new DropdownField("DropDown1","DropDown",
   array(

        '-1' => 'Option1',
        '1' => 'Option2',
        ))));
}
```

But The Main Tab already has a field named theme under it which is generated by default. I need to keep this field separated from the tabs which I have added...maybe creating a new sub-tab for it...Please tell me how I can achieve this...Currently it appears under every tab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the default 'Theme' field altogether if you'd like.

Put this line before all the code you posted:

`$fields->removeByName('Theme');`